# google analytics: tracking website and it's blog in one web property but with different profiles

Tags: google-analytics

i am trying to track website www.mywebsite.com and it's blog, blog.mywebsite.com with google analytics. i have created one Web Property and two Profiles on this Web Property, one for blog, one for website.

initially, i tried following instructions at http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSite.html and pasted following code to both sites headers:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-12345-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'mywebsite.com']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

to demonstrate the problem, let's say blog.mywebsite.com has a page "about.html", and www.mywebsite.com has a page "products.php"

now google analytics displays "products.php" (and other www.mywebsite.com subpages) visits on **blog profile** (and very big number of hits in first day of blog installation)!

how can i make **website** profile display only "products.php" visits, and **blog profile** only "about.html" visits?

i also realized that i missed the dot (i put 'mywebsite.com' instead of '.mywebsite.com') but i am not sure there is a big difference

currently i modified blog's ga code to:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-12345-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

and added

```
_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
```

to website's ga code

but i am not sure if it will change situation..

or is the only solution to have two separate Web Properties for blog and site?

Comment: occurs that my initial solution was good, i only needed to add filters to new profile. this link: http://www.bigdaylight.com/analytics/filtering-subdomains-in-google-analytics/ was extremely helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separating pageviews from one website and another isn't done by the tracking code setup, but by configuring filters on profiles.

You need to create an advanced filter / Include / Hostname / for each profile.

The drawback of such approach comes when you use Event : you can't filter Events for the moment, then you get the same Events stats on the 2 profiles.

e-Commerce transactions need to also be filtered out through the transaction ID.